# Do all the tables in SQL have to be connected?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this scheme in CaseStudio where I have multiple instances of keeping the address of something. I have the adress of a client, address of an event, address of a user. And in order to have it in 3rd normal form I have a table called cities which has only "city" as PK and its ZIP code. But I do not know if I have to connect it to all the others tables which contain the name of the city, or if it can be without any relation to anything.

Comment: Tables don't *have to* have a foreign key relationship to other tables.  But if the data structure calls for it, there are certainly cases where they *should*.

Comment: There is no rule/condition that a table must be related to any other table; if you're ever going to use it in joins, I would recommend making proper foreign key relationships and indexes, but it's not a requirement.

Comment: I do not believe that you understood [data normalization well](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-rdbms-concepts.htm).  You may want to revisit it.  This seems to be OK as well: http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Comment: Cities have multiple zip codes, so how would you get the correct one for the address with this schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unlikely that this table would be unconnected to anything else. You would want the address to relate in some way to the city. Think how you would query the address, you would wan t return the person name (from your user or peopel table), the strett addess from you address table, the city from you city table. But you woudl have to know how each of these pieces of information are related to each other.

Personally I find that having a separate city and zipcode table is really overkill when it comes to addresses, but if this is an academic exercise, they might want you to break it out to get to the correct normal form. Normally in this case you would have a cityid as a column in the city table and then the address table would contain the cityid field and there would be a foriegn key set up to the city table to maintain teh data integrity.